# MongoDB aggregation: transform list of documents into list

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this documents:

```
[ { id: 1 }, {id: 2}, {id: 3} ]
```

I want to transform that into:

```
{ ids: [1, 2, 3] }
```

or

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Which is the most efficient pipeline for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$group` and `$project` stage.

For the first result - `{ ids: [1, 2, 3] }`, please use the following MongoDB aggregation pipeline.

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      ids: { $push: "$id" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      ids: 1
    }
  }
]
```

You can get desired result only use `$group` stage in above pipeline, but there is a field `_id: null`, so you can remove this field using `$project` stage.